# Convert date + hour to timestamp - pandas / python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataset where I have 2 columns in a data frame - Date in YYYY-MM-DD format and another column with Hour in format 0100 (for 1am) until 2300 (for 12pm).

```
Date          Hour
2017-01-01   0200
2017-01-01   0400
```

etc
In order to get it ready for Time series mode, I want to convert these into datetime objects and concatenate these columns. Example output desired: 2017-01-01 01:00:00, etc

I have tried `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` and converted this into datetime object, But I'm struggling with the Hour column. Please help

Answer (score 3):

This is one way. The trick is to note that `pd.to_datetime` is actually quite flexible: it accepts strings of the format "YYYY-MM-DD HHMM".

I assume here that your Hour is given as a string (otherwise leading zeros are not possible).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-01'],
                   'Hour': ['0200', '0400']})

# as per @COLDSPEED's suggestion
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Hour'])

print(df)

#          Date  Hour            DateTime
# 0  2017-01-01  0200 2017-01-01 02:00:00
# 1  2017-01-01  0400 2017-01-01 04:00:00

print(df.dtypes)

# Date                object
# Hour                object
# DateTime    datetime64[ns]
# dtype: object
```

---

Previous version with `pd.DataFrame.apply` is *possible* but inefficient:

```
df['DateTime'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date'] + ' ' + x['Hour'], axis=1)\
                   .apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Hour)`

Comment: Thanks so much  @coldspeed for your help!